# Слово "исполин"

Tags: этимология

И еще хочу спросить о происхождении слов. Слово "великан" понятно — от слова "великий" в значении "большой". А вот что за слово "исполин"? Оно вообще русское?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит от русск.-церк.-слав. исполинъ (γίγας; Изборн. Святосл. 1073 г. и др.), ср.: ст.-слав. споловъ (род. мн. γίγας; Супр.), др.-польск. stolim, stolin «исполин», кашубск. stolem — то же. Связано с именем спалов, побежденных готами на территории соврем. Южн. России. В русск.-церк.-слав. текстах исполинъ встречается неоднократно уже в ХI в. . Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Да, слово русское.